# Создать "Hello world" с выводом в консоль

Tags: php, консоль

Написал на PHP "Hello world" открывается в браузере, все ок.

Но что нужно сделать, чтобы результат выходил в консоль?

В командной строке ввожу "php.exe "hello world.php" как пишут во всех мануалах, но получаю ответ "php.exe command not found" Хотя PHP установлен. ОС - Винда

Comment: Могу порекомендовать почитать маны по теме и не бросаться с места в карьер: обучитесь сначала элементарному.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно же: директория с `php.exe` не является текущей или не находится в переменной окружения PATH. Попробуйте вызвать с указанием пути до `php.exe`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Выручил